# Where is dns_stream_ref() definition located?

Tags: systemd

I am looking for a definition of the function **dns_stream_ref()** in the source tree of systemd. The declaration was found in resolved-dns-stream.h, this function is called from some source files. However, there isn't any definition of this function in resolved-dns-stream.c. Moreover, I couldn't see the definition of this function anywhere in the sources.

Does anyone know where and how the function **dns_stream_ref()** is defined?

Answer (score 0):

It's defined by the use of the `DEFINE_TRIVIAL_REF_UNREF_FUNC` macro in resolved-dns-stream.c. That will expand to code which implements the _ref and _unref functions, which count using the `n_ref` member of `DnsStream`.